# internal alkyne stability to strong alkali

Tags: organic-chemistry

Internal alkynes are relatively electron rich and are not *usually* prone to attack by strong (nucleophilic) bases such as hydroxide or alkoxide.

However, this isn't always the case.  A [very nice overview](https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/faculty/reusch/virttxtjml/addyne1.htm) of the most common reactions of alkynes says:

> The sp-hybrid carbon atoms of the triple-bond render alkynes more electrophilic than similarly substituted alkenes. As a result, alkynes sometimes undergo addition reactions initiated by bonding to a nucleophile. This mode of reaction, illustrated below, is generally not displayed by alkenes, unless the double-bond is activated by electronegative substituents, e.g. $\ce{F2C=CF2}$, or by conjugation with an electron withdrawing group.
>
> $\ce{HC≡CH   +   KOC2H5    —>[in C2H5OH at 150 ºC]   H2C=CH-OC2H5}$

**I'm interested in more information about this and similar reactions, particular for internal (not acetylenic) alkynes.**

Unfortunately, the linked page doesn't provide a reference for this reaction, and searching in Google Scholar for "internal alkyne" "potassium hydroxide" doesn't provide useful results.

Thus my questions are:

1. **Does hydroxide ever react similarly with internal alkynes, at *any* temperature?**  If so, under what conditions?
2. How long does the ethoxide reaction indicated above (at 150 °C) take?  Days?  Hours?  Minutes?  Would it be significantly different for an internal alkyne rather than acetylene?
3. In the case of a hydroxide reaction, would the ultimate product be a ketone (a.k.a. base catalyzed hydration)?

Comment: I can't read German, but [this paper](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jlac.19566010106/abstract;jsessionid=0EED1277075A0B4A50008E02EB4949F0.f03t03) is probably relevant. From what I can tell, it is describing the reaction between acetylene, an alcohol/phenol (including ethanol), and KOH at elevated pressures to give a vinyl aryl or vinyl alkyl ether.

Comment: There are also multiple patents describing how the reaction can be carried out in industry, for example [this one](http://patft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=2472084.PN.&OS=PN/2472084&RS=PN/2472084). Page 9 states that the reaction with MeOH (to form vinyl methyl ether) was run with KOMe catalyst at 45 psi, 145 deg C, for 40 hours giving a 96% yield.

Comment: And I did another search on Reaxys for vinyl ethers of the form $\ce{R^1HC=C(OR^2)R^3}$ but sadly no syntheses from internal alkynes turned up. I'll leave somebody else more qualified to try to rationalise it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [A Textbook of Organic Chemistry](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22hydroxide%20and%20the%20reverse%20of%20this%20reaction%22&=) by V. K. Ahluwalia and Madhuri Goyal

> 1-Butyne may be isomerised to a more stable 2-butyne in presence of alcoholic potassium hydroxide and the reverse of this reaction may occur with sodamide

(see 17.2.1 of [Best Synthetic Methods: Acetylenes, Allenes and Cumulenes](https://books.google.com/books?id=jBkCH-v9-j8C&pg=PA320&dq=1-Butyne%20isomerised%20%202-butyne&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOvKTr6OTQAhVZVWMKHduABboQ6AEIPjAG#v=onepage&q=1-Butyne%20isomerised%20%202-butyne&f=false) for reaction conditions in the 2-alkyne to 1-alkyne direction, actually many relevant reactions are in this book)

So in the present of the strong base $\ce{NaNH2}$ the internal alkyne $\ce{H3CC#CCH3}$ rearranges to $\ce{HC#CCH2CH3}$

My thinking is that with just hydroxide the more stable 2-butyne is favored, while if an even-stronger base is used, that fact that the acetylenic-H can deprotonate pulls the equilibrium toward 1-butyne.

Additionally, see [17.2.11](https://books.google.com/books?id=jBkCH-v9-j8C&pg=PA331&dq=%2217.2.11%20isomerisation%20of%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSwbn-6uTQAhVB7WMKHS3MBLsQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%2217.2.11%20isomerisation%20of%22&f=false) Isomerisation of 1,4 bis(alkoxy)-2-butynes to the corresponding allenes, which is catalyzed by t-BuOK.

Add see table 17.1 "Base catalyzed isomerisations of acetylenic compounds" about 10 different internal acetylene reactions are listed in the table.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'll probably accept & award in the next day or two (unless a better answer materializes).  I'm especially impressed w/ table 17.1.  It seems like alkynes can readily isomerize to allenes or other slightly more stable isomers under basic conditions.